# Dynamic button click hide and show functionality in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have hide and show functionality on dynamically generated cards after form submission.

```
{{#each newaction}}
                 <div class="workflowcard">
                 <div class="module-card-small">
                     <div class="res-border"></div>
                    <div class="card-img">{{team}}</div>
                    <div class="res-content">

                    <div class=" newaction-name">{{action_title}}</div><hr>
                    <div class="newaction-des">{{description}}</div>
                   <!-- <div class=" due-on">Due on:{{d_date}}</div><hr>-->



                     </div>
                      <div class="due">

                       Due on:
                        <div>
                            <div class="day-stamp">{{weekday d_date}}</div>
                        <div class="date-stamp">{{date d_date}}</div>
                        <div class="month-stamp">{{month d_date}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                       {{> actioncardsubcontent}} 
                </div>
     <div class="btn-box">
      <button type="button" class="cancelsub">Hide Option</button>
      <button type="submit" class="createbtnsub">Show Options</button>
    </div>

    </div>

            </div>

                {{/each}}                                                                                                                                              
        </div>
    </div>  

    <template name="actioncardsubcontent">

        <div class="subcontent" >

                <div class="modulepath"><div>{{module_list}}</div></div>
                <div class="linkto"><div>Linked To: &nbsp;<div class="linkto-color">{{link}}</div></div></div>
                <div class="description"><div>Notes:<br>{{description}}</div></div>
                </div>

    </template>
```

When I click on show options  button the action card subcontent is displaying and when I click on hide option it is hiding.
The problem is, the hide and show functionality is applying for all the cards which are creating dynamically at a time when I click on single card. I understand the reason is I have given the class name for the buttons. So how to stop that and make it work to current target.

Here is my JS:

```
Template.actioncardsubcontent.rendered = function(){
    this.$(".subcontent").hide();
};

Template.workflow.events({
"click .createbtnsub":function(){
$('.subcontent').show();
},
"click .cancelsub":function(){
$('.subcontent').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is give a unique ID for each iteration to your cards div class attribute.

in JSTL usually has indexId attribute. You can use that and set your class.

Sample:

```
{{#each newaction indexId="i"}}
{{/each}}  

  <div class="btn-box">
      <button type="button" class="cancelsub<%=i%>">Hide Option</button>
      <button type="submit" class="createbtnsub<%=i%>">Show Options</button>
    </div>
```

In your javascript:

use i to hide.

Comment: I want that buttons also display dynamically if I write buttons out of each loop it doesn't work

Comment: You need to create\generate the buttons ID dynamically in the for each loop. You need to provide it an index.  <div class="btn-box">
      <button type="button" class="cancelsub<%=i%>">Hide Option</button>
      <button type="submit" class="createbtnsub<%=i%>">Show Options</button>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here. The one I prefer is to put everything in the `{{#each}}` into its own template. If you do that, you can put the button click events inside of the child template's event which makes it much simpler to manipulate your data. An example:

Templates:

```
<template name='workflow'>
    {{#each newaction}}
        {{> card}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name='card'>
    <div class="workflowcard">
        <div class="module-card-small">
            <div class="res-border"></div>
            <div class="card-img">{{team}}</div>
            <div class="res-content">

            <div class=" newaction-name">{{action_title}}</div><hr>
            <div class="newaction-des">{{description}}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="due">
            Due on:
                <div>
                    <div class="day-stamp">{{weekday d_date}}</div>
                    <div class="date-stamp">{{date d_date}}</div>
                    <div class="month-stamp">{{month d_date}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            {{> actioncardsubcontent}} 
        </div>

        <div class="btn-box">
            <button type="button" class="cancelsub">Hide Option</button>
            <button type="submit" class="createbtnsub">Show Options</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Javascript ([template.$ docs](http://docs.meteor.com/v1.3.2/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-$)):

```
Template.cards.events({
    "click .createbtnsub":function(event, template){
        template.$('.subcontent').show();
    },
    "click .cancelsub":function(event, template){
        template.$('.subcontent').hide();
    }
});
```

-- OR --

You can do a better DOM query.

Without more info on what is actually in the `actioncardsubcontent` template or proper testing, this is a best guess on what you're trying to find. You should be able to tweak this query to meet your specific needs easily enough through trial and error. Please read the [jQuery Traversing docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) as it should clear this up a bit for you.

```
Template. workflow.events({
    "click .createbtnsub":function(event, template){
       $(event.target).siblings('.due').find('.subcontent').show();
    },
    "click .cancelsub":function(event, template){
       $(event.target).siblings('.due').find('.subcontent').hide();
    }
});
```